# JQuery : If Contains Given String then Direct to Related Page

Tags: jquery, html

i have a small project. On this project. I have table which contains football league names.
All 's on table are links.
On clicking one of these links, i need to direct my page to related league table.
For example;

if i have clicked premier league from my table, i need to direct my page to premier league table page.

I've written small code but it didnt work.

```
$(function() {
var tableRow = $("td").filter(function() {
return $(this).text() == "Premier League";
})
window.location.href = "RELATEDURL";
});
```

Can anyone help me about it please ?
Thank you.

Edit 1 : I get the names of the league with this method.
I need to apply to this format.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
$.getJSON("getleaguetablesURL",function(data) {
console.log(data);
$.each(data, function(index, value) {
$('#leaguetable').append("<tr><td class='team'><a href='#'>"
+value.Name+"</a></td></tr>");
});
$('#leaguetable').listview('refresh');
})
});
```

Comment: You do know that's what `anchor` elements were created for, don't you?

Comment: I don't understand, why don't you just add the url in the `href` of `.team a` instead of using `#`? Your JSON is actually `getleaguetablesURL` so I assume that the league tables URLs are passed in this JSON…?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using `<a>` tags instead of JavaScript. You can use some CSS to stretch an `<a>` to the size of a `<td>` so the whole cell can be clicked.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/jyqXF/)

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="/premierleague.htm">Premier league</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="/anotherleague.htm">Another league</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
a {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    padding:2px;
}

table {
    width:300px;
}

td {
    border:1px solid #000;
    padding:0;
}
```

---

**EDIT:** Since you're getting your league names from JSON you can simply fill in the anchor `href` there.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $.getJSON("getleaguetablesURL",function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $.each(data, function(index, value) {
            var url = "RELATEDURL";
            $('#leaguetable').append("<tr><td class='team'>" +
                "<a href='" + url + "'>" +
                value.Name+"</a></td></tr>");
        });
        $('#leaguetable').listview('refresh');
    })
});
```

Comment: i know this of course my friend.But i cannot use this way, because i get the league names with JSON data.

Comment: Then a better course of action would be to manipulate the text and `href` of the `<a>`

Answer (score 0):

You can always use `jQuery`, although keep in mind that if the user has its `javascript` turned off this won't work.

Edited the fiddle example above to the following:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jyqXF/3/)

See if that works for ya.